# How to encrypt jpeg file correctly using xor operation

Tags: c#, encryption, jpeg

I have a problem with encrypting JPEG file using xor operation.
Here is how I am decoding the file:

```
        Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open,   FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

        return bitmapSource;
```

Here is how I am encoding and encrypting it(bs is decoded BitmapSource):

```
        int stride = bs.PixelWidth * 3;
        int size = bs.PixelHeight * stride;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[size];
        bs.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

        pixels = xoring(pixels, size);

        int width = bs.PixelWidth;
        int height = bs.PixelHeight;

        BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            bs.DpiX,
            bs.DpiY,
            bs.Format,
            bs.Palette,
            pixels,
            stride);

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(outName, FileMode.Create);
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        myTextBlock.Text = "Codec Author is: " + encoder.CodecInfo.Author.ToString();
        encoder.FlipHorizontal = false;
        encoder.FlipVertical = false;
        encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
        encoder.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate0;
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        encoder.Save(stream);
```

This is xoring function:

```
    public byte[] xoring(byte[] data, int size)
    {
        const string key = "abc";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            data[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ (byte)key[i % key.Length]);
        return data;
    }
```

I am expecting the image to be completly noise, but I am getting something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHnLu.png

This the original file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLw71.png

I would appreciate any help! It seems like if only one color channel was encrypted...

Comment: Yes, I meant encryption making use of XOR operation ;) I edited the question.

Comment: I am not writing if for NASA, just for JPEG encrpytion learing purpooses ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a constant key there is no chance for a decent level of security. In fact, as your images show some of the data still 'jump' out of the resulting image..

The missing component is a way to change your encoding key during encrytion. The most obviuos way is to use a Random generator to create a new encoding byte for each XOR operation.

This way the real key will be the seed you use to setup the Random at class level(!):

```
Random R = new Randowm(2014);
```

Or possibly something like:

```
Random R = new Randowm(imageStreamSource.Length);
```

This will set it up in a way that will allow you to decode later.

You then Xor by creating fresh key as

```
byte key = (byte) R.Next(256);
```

Comment: Note that the documentation of System.Random explicitly says not to use it for cryptography. Also, it does not guarantee stable sequences between .NET versions. There is System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider, but I don't think it can be initialized to generate reproducible sequences at all. What is needed here is a proper standard encryption algorithm such as provided by the [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Yes, this is true but as the OP mentioned he doesn't need professional grade security here. - I'm curious if the .NET versions we have seen so far have ever changed their random algorithm to break code that relied on it?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is similar to the issues with the [ECB mode of block ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).

What happens here is that any repetition of data in your original file also results in repetition in the ciphertext.

For example, if your bits are "00000..." over a long stretch, then the encrypted version will just be your key repeated over the same stretch. The pattern of repetition is preserved. (Obviously it is not a good property of an encryption algorithm to reveal your key like that, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: Thanks, your answer was good as well but below was presented also the solution.